# How to print a word and its following char for Specfic length from String in Java

Tags: java, string

Hello guys i am stuck with a small problem and i don't know weather its possible or not. In the below `String foo` i have list of names and from address where they belong to. so my question is that is there a possible way that i can print all the `name` and its following character till the next space.

```
String foo="Hello my name is name Suryam from India"
          +"Hello my name is name Shekar from Europe"
          +"Hello my name is name Raju from United States"
          +"Hello my name is name Chandramouli from  Bangladesh"
          +"Hello my name is name Ravi from Austrila"
          +"Hello my name is name Sai from Singapore"
          +"Hello my name is name Naresh from Japan";
```

i want to print expected output to be something like.

### Output

```
name Suryam 
name Shekar
name Raju 
name Chandramouli 
name Suryam 
name Ravi 
name Sai 
name Naresh
```

Comment: Sure. You would want to use a regular expression. And make your life much easier by not pulling together these strings into a single one, rather go with a list of strings for example.

Comment: its just an example String but my String is a Huge sentence where i need to find name related scenario with following character.

Comment: There we go: then you have unclear requirements. That sounds like your sentences might look quite different. But the question "how to parse it" very much depends on what you know about its layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex `is\\sname\\s(\\w+)\\s` to fetch the data,pay attention to the duplicate name in each record

```
    String foo="Hello my name is name Suryam from India"
            +"Hello my name is name Shekar from Europe"
            +"Hello my name is name Raju from United States"
            +"Hello my name is name Chandramouli from  Bangladesh"
            +"Hello my name is name Ravi from Austrila"
            +"Hello my name is name Sai from Singapore"
            +"Hello my name is name Naresh from Japan";
    String regex = "is\\sname\\s(\\w+)\\s";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(foo);
    while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println("name " + matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Output:

```
name Suryam
name Shekar
name Raju
name Chandramouli
name Ravi
name Sai
name Naresh
```